# Size of buffer for publishing multiples mqtt topics and values of sensors

Tags: c++, memory-management, mqtt

I wanna publish a lot of sensor data with mqtt but I don't know if my ESP8266 will support it. I have like a total of 16 sensors (temp,Hum,Lux,PIR) distributed in 3 floors, each sensor will provide a 2 byte data (PIR only 1 byte) and I am gonna publish it with 1 second samplig. The problem is that I don't know how exactly works the PubSubClient.h, if it will send all the data at the same time or will send it by parts.

If by any chance I clear the payload char each time the esp8266 published 4 data sensors per example, it will help or not ?

Here is a part of the code, don't mind some values please it's not finished yet. I post only this part so the entire code is very large because it receives data from 4 Xbee's and other things.

```
char msg[50];  // Not sure about the exact size of the payload, I don't know if it will publish all the data at the same time or what 

// Dont mind please, it is not finihed yet
float tempC, Humidity, Lux = 0; 
int pir_int = 0;

float tempC, Humidity, Lux = 0; 
int pir_int = 0;

float tempC, Humidity, Lux = 0; 
int pir_int = 0;

float tempC, Humidity, Lux = 0; 
int pir_int = 0;

// Declaració dels topics mqtt
// Soterrani
#define st_temp "casa/st/soterrani/temperatura"
#define st_hum "casa/st/soterrani/humitat"
#define st_pir "casa/st/soterrani/pir"
#define st_llums "casa/st/soterrani/llums" // per codi actuador
#define st_lux "casa/st/soterrani/lux"

#define st_rent "casa/st/soterrani/rentadora" // per codi actuador
#define st_cald "casa/st/soterrani/caldera" // per codi actuador


// Cuina
#define st_temp "casa/pb/cuina/temperatura"
#define st_hum "casa/pb/cuina/humitat"
#define st_llums "casa/pb/cuina/llums" // per codi actuador
#define st_co "casa/pb/cuina/co"

// Saló
#define st_temp "casa/pb/salo/temperatura"
#define st_hum "casa/pb/salo/humitat"
#define st_pir "casa/pb/salo/pir"
#define st_llums "casa/pb/salo/llums" // per codi actuador
#define st_alarma "casa/pb/salo/alarma" // per codi actuador
#define st_lux "casa/pb/salo/lux"

// Dormitori
#define st_temp "casa/pp/dormitori/temperatura"
#define st_hum "casa/pp/dormitori/humitat"
#define st_pir "casa/pp/dormitori/pir"
#define st_llums "casa/pp/dormitori/llums" // per codi actuador
#define st_lux "casa/pp/dormitori/lux"

// Oficina
#define st_temp "casa/pp/oficina/temperatura"
#define st_hum "casa/pp/oficina/humitat"
#define st_llums "casa/pp/oficina/llums" // per codi actuador
#define st_lux "casa/pp/oficina/lux"

void loop()
{
  // Fem la primera connexió del client i les següents que siguin necessàries
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }

    // Inicialitzem la funció de tractament de dades 
  parseData();


  // Publiquem les dades dels sensors cada un cert temps
  long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 29000) {
    lastMsg = now;
    // tractem les variables amb 2 enters i 2 decimals de precisió i les convertim a string
    // Soterrani
    String Pir_s = String(pir_int);
    client.publish(st_pir, Pir_s);
    client.publish(st_temp, dtostrf(tempC, 4, 2, msgbuf));
    client.publish(st_hum, dtostrf(Humidity, 4, 2, msgbuf));
    client.publish(st_lux, dtostrf(Lux, 4, 2, msgbuf); // revisar


// Not finished yet, here are the other sensor data I wanna publish

    String Pir_s = String(pir_int);
    client.publish(st_pir, Pir_s);
    client.publish(st_temp, dtostrf(tempC, 4, 2, msgbuf));
    client.publish(st_hum, dtostrf(Humidity, 4, 2, msgbuf));
    client.publish(st_lux, dtostrf(Lux, 4, 2, msgbuf); // revisar

    String Pir_s = String(pir_int);
    client.publish(st_pir, Pir_s);
    client.publish(st_temp, dtostrf(tempC, 4, 2, msgbuf));
    client.publish(st_hum, dtostrf(Humidity, 4, 2, msgbuf));
    client.publish(st_lux, dtostrf(Lux, 4, 2, msgbuf); // revisar

    String Pir_s = String(pir_int);
    client.publish(st_pir, Pir_s);
    client.publish(st_temp, dtostrf(tempC, 4, 2, msgbuf));
    client.publish(st_hum, dtostrf(Humidity, 4, 2, msgbuf));
    client.publish(st_lux, dtostrf(Lux, 4, 2, msgbuf); // revisar


    
  }

  // Fem una connexió en cada loop amb client per refrescar dades per publicar i mantenir la connexió 
  client.loop();

  
}
```

Comment: So all 16 sensors go into ONE ESP8266?!?  That seems excessive to me.  Best practice is that each sensor reading get its own MQTT Topic, which your code looks like its doing.  I usually break up my sensors to no more than 4 or 5 per Publisher, and that is only if I don't have enough MCUs to support all my sensors.  What happens if that one MCU goes down?  The MQTT Brokers can handles hundreds of Publishers, so that side of things isn't a problem.  You might want to consider breaking that up a bit.

Comment: @JDAllen First of all thanks for answering. No, the sensor data comes from diferrents XBee modules, the ESP8266 only parse the data received and publish it. So based on what you are saying, the size of the char buffer don't matter because it will only contain 1 data sensor at each publish time? Or do I need to use more than 1 char buffer considering all the 16 sensors? Thanks.

Comment: @JDAllen Sorry, Now I understand what you meant by saying that all 16 sensors go into only one esp8266. I can add another one if the first goes down. Thanks for pointing that out.